# PyQt event propagation from ignorant model to view

Tags: user-interface, event-handling, pyqt

I'm trying to write a GUI in PyQt that has a network layer which should notify the GUI of any new messages that are received over the network. In C#, I would have written a delegate/event pair in my net class:

```
//event handler for propagating new message to GUI
public delegate void MessageReceived(String from, String msg);
public event MessageReceived messageReceived;
```

This way, all the GUI needs is a reference to the **`messageReceived`** variable (and the net class remains agnostic).

Now, I've read all about signals and slots in PyQt, but I haven't been able to find anything that explains how to replicate the above functionality. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've only recently learned to appreciate the awesomeness of `SIGNAL()`, and it's not too complicated.

You'd want to create a new class that is threaded:

```
class NetworkThing(QtCore.QThread):
  def __init__(self, parent = None):
    super(NetworkThing, self).__init__(parent)

  def run(self):
    while True:
      time.wait(1.0)
      # Do your background stuff, and then emit:
      self.emit(QtCore.SIGNAL('messageRecieved(QString)'), 'The response text.')
```

From within your main application initialization function, you need to prepare a new variable and a new `SIGNAL()` catcher:

```
self.networkThing = NetworkThing()
self.connect(self.networkThing, QtCore.SIGNAL('messageRecieved(QString)'), self.processEvent)
```

Now, the response of the networking thread it piped instantly to the function `processEvent()`.

---

Just as a side note, the `run()` function of `NetworkThing()` is automatically run by PyQt4, so there is rarely a time when you manually call it. Instead, call `self.networkThing.start()`.

If you want to look at a pretty nice example of this stuff, read this article: http://diotavelli.net/PyQtWiki/Threading,_Signals_and_Slots.

Comment: awesome, thanks! I miss the asynchronous c# functionality, but maybe I can be won over...